# Can we decrease the build time by disabling the sonar indexing file logs while building a java project?

Tags: build, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Huge build timings are effecting our production timelines very much in a negative manner. We tried all possible ways to decrease the build timings like increasing the no.of threads..etc. We have a huge list of files that should be excluded from coverage, is mentioned in the global settings of our sonar production server application. Most of the files listed are specific to a repository. The list is applicable to all the other projects (all other repositories) too in our sonar application (as it is a global setting) so in each and every build irrespective of repository the mvn-sonar plugin is indexing the huge list of files in console output.

We thought of customizing the exclusion list on project level will reduce the build timings, but still there is no considerable reduction in build time. Could anyone please help on this ?

Comment: You'll have to show your sonar properties and some of your output.  Do you have debug output enabled?

Comment: Thank you David, will provide the properties but before that we upgraded the sonar server version to 8.6 from 7.9.6 before the issue came into existence. After we downgraded the version to 7.9.6, the builds are speed up as sonar is taking 3 minutes rather than 39 minutes with 8.6 version for the same codebase. Most of the people are suffering with this build timing increments when they are upgraded to latest version of sonar.

Comment: Probably best to provide all relevant details in the sonar source forum.